# Finding objects that meet a range of two number properties from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, algorithm

could I get some suggestions on how I can efficiently find items to delete based off the `start` and `end` properties.

**Cases:**

- `added` - if an existing item start/period was changed, the new updated item is added.
- `deleted` - if an existing item start/period was changed and the existing item needs deleting.
- `updated` - if an existing item cost was changed and the existing item needs updating.
- `unchanged` - if there was no changes.

Thank you.

```
const existingItems = [
    {
        id: '111',
        start: 0,
        end: 10,
        cost: 100
    },
    {
        id: '222',
        start: 20,
        end: 30,
        cost: 200
    },
];

const updatedItems = [
    {
        id: '111',
        start: 0,
        end: 9,
        cost: 42
    },
    {
        id: '222',
        start: 20,
        end: 30,
        cost: 400 // cost change, so only added to updated
    },
    { // ignored
        id: '333',
        start: 20,
        end: 30,
        cost: 400
    },
];

const addedItem = [];
const deletedItems = [];

existingItems.forEach((existingItem) => {
  const existingStartEnd = `${existingItem.id}-${existingItem.start}-${existingItem.end}`

  updatedItems.forEach((updatedItem) => {
    const updatedStartEnd = `${updatedItem.id}-${updatedItem.start}-${updatedItem.end}`

    if (updatedItem.id === existingItem.id && (existingStartEnd !== updatedStartEnd & existingItem.cost === updatedItem.cost)) {
      deletedItems.push(existingItem);
    }
  })
})

// expected result
const items = {
  deleted: [
    {
        id: '111',
        start: 0,
        end: 10,
        cost: 100
    }
  ],
  added: [
    {
        id: '111',
        start: 0,
        end: 9,
        cost: 42
    },
  ],
  updated: [
    {
        id: '222',
        start: 20,
        end: 30,
        cost: 400
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object, and in turn basic set operations...

Specifically, convert `existingItems` and `updatedItems` into Map objects, using the combination of the attributes of `id`, `start`, and `end` as the Map Key, and the entire object as the Map Value.  Then apply the following basic set operations...

- Added objects:  Find all Map Keys in `updatedItems` not in `existingItems`.
- Updated objects:  Find all Map Keys in `updatedItems` also in `existingItems` in which the `cost` attribute is not the same.
- Deleted objects: Find all Map Keys in `existingItems` not in `updatedItems`.

Note in the Code Snippet below that when turning a Map object into an array, such as `[ ...updatedMap ]`, that the result is an array of `[ key, value ]` pairs, and hence the reference to `m[ 0 ]` (the Map key) and `m[ 1 ]` (the Map value)...

```js
function changes( existing, updated ) {

  function key( o ) {
    return o.id + '|' + o.start + '|' + o.end;
  }

  existingMap = new Map( existingItems.map( o => [ key( o ), o ] ) );
  updatedMap  = new Map( updatedItems.map(  o => [ key( o ), o ] ) );

  const changedItems = {};
  
  changedItems.added =   [ ...updatedMap ]
    .filter( m => ! existingMap.has( m[ 0 ] ) )
    .map( m => m[ 1 ] );
    
  changedItems.deleted = [ ...existingMap ]
    .filter( m => ! updatedMap.has( m[ 0 ] ) )
    .map( m => m[ 1 ] );
    
  changedItems.updated = [ ...updatedMap ]
    .filter( m => existingMap.has( m[ 0 ] )  &&  updatedMap.get( m[ 0 ] ).cost !== existingMap.get( m[ 0 ] ).cost )
    .map( m => m[ 1 ] );

  changedItems.unchanged = [ ...updatedMap ]
    .filter( m => existingMap.has( m[ 0 ] )  &&  updatedMap.get( m[ 0 ] ).cost === existingMap.get( m[ 0 ] ).cost )
    .map( m => m[ 1 ] );
    
  return changedItems;
  
}


const existingItems = [
    {
        id: '111',
        start: 0,
        end: 10,
        cost: 100
    },
    {
        id: '222',
        start: 20,
        end: 30,
        cost: 200
    },
    {
        id: '333',
        start: 20,
        end: 30,
        cost: 200
    },
];

const updatedItems = [
    {
        id: '111',
        start: 0,
        end: 9,
        cost: 42
    },
    {
        id: '222',
        start: 20,
        end: 30,
        cost: 400 // cost change, so only added to updated
    },
];

let result = changes( existingItems, updatedItems )
console.log( result );
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not quite work for me, because if you had another item within `existingItems`, then `deleted` array will have another items

Comment: Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: @Rayzzz The solution I have presented effectively assumes that `id, start, & end` represent a unique combination, with `cost` attributed to this compound identifier.  That being said, before I suggest a tweak based on your comment, one critical question is whether the `existingItems` or `updatedItems` arrays can have multiple entries for the same `id`?  For example, is it possible to have two entries in `existingItems` like `id:100,start:0,end:20,cost:50` and `id:100,start:20,end:40,cost:100`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want.  We start by finding all the unique ids, then fold them into our output object, with a nested conditional checking the various places they might need to go:

```js
const changes = (xs, ys) => [... new Set ([...xs .map (x => x.id), ...ys .map (y => y.id)])] .reduce (
  (res, id, _, __, x = xs .find (x => x .id == id), y = ys .find (y => y .id == id)) => (
    (!x)
      ? res // ignored.  But wouldn't it be better to have a spot for these too?
    : (!y) 
      ? res .deleted .push (x)
    : (x .start !== y .start || x .end !== y .end) 
      ? res .added .push (y) && res .deleted .push (x)
    : (x .cost !== y .cost) 
      ? res .updated .push (y)
    : res
  ) && res, 
  {deleted: [], added: [], updated: []}
)


const existingItems = [{id: "111", start: 0, end: 10, cost: 100}, {id: "222", start: 20, end: 30, cost: 200}]
const updatedItems = [{id: "111", start: 0, end: 9, cost: 42}, {id: "222", start: 20, end: 30, cost: 400}, {id: "333", start: 20, end: 30, cost: 400}];

console .log (changes (existingItems, updatedItems))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I do find it odd that you don't want to track the newly added objects as well (like "333").  If you did, it would be trivial to add them, and the spot is marked with a comment.